# VBA - Search .csv for keyword then Paste row into another Excel sheet (Consolidate code)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

Sorry if this question seems basic, I'm just learning some VBA out of necessity.

I have this sheet that uses a macro to pull in data from a .csv file. It searches a column on the csv for a word (like "Apple" seen below) then pastes in the appropriate cell range on the other sheet.

The code is set up where it runs through a bunch of these code blocks individually with different search words and destination cell ranges. I'm trying to find a way to consolidate this code and perhaps make it faster. My 1st thought is to create arrays for the search words and cell ranges then loop through them..

```
'Apple ***********************************************************************

  Windows("Produce.xls").Activate

    ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlNormal
    Set F = Columns("C:C").Find(What:="Apple*", After:=Range("C1"), LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not F Is Nothing Then
    
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Find(What:="Apple*", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
      :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
      False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
s = ActiveCell.Address

A = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Address
B = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Address
C = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Address
D = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Address
E = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Address
F = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Address
G = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Address
H = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Address
I = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Address
J = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Address
K = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Address
L = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 12).Address
M = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13).Address
N = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14).Address
O = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 15).Address
p = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 16).Address
q = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17).Address
r = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 18).Address
s = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 19).Address
t = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 20).Address
u = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 21).Address
v = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 22).Address
w = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 23).Address
x = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 24).Address
Range(A, x).Select
Selection.Copy
    Windows("Log Sheet.xlsm").Activate
    Range("Z3:Z26").Select ' <--- Range of cells in desk sheet to paste to
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
      :=False, Transpose:=True
         Else
    Msg = MsgBox("No Apple Data")
End If

'Orange ***********************************************************************

  Windows("Produce.xls").Activate

    ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlNormal
    Set F = Columns("C:C").Find(What:="Orange*", After:=Range("C1"), LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not F Is Nothing Then
    
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Find(What:="Orange*", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
      :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
      False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
s = ActiveCell.Address

A = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Address
B = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Address
C = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Address
D = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Address
E = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Address
F = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Address
G = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Address
H = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Address
I = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Address
J = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Address
K = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Address
L = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 12).Address
M = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13).Address
N = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14).Address
O = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 15).Address
p = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 16).Address
q = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17).Address
r = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 18).Address
s = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 19).Address
t = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 20).Address
u = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 21).Address
v = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 22).Address
w = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 23).Address
x = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 24).Address
Range(A, x).Select
Selection.Copy
    Windows("Log Sheet.xlsm").Activate
    Range("E3:E26").Select ' <--- Range of cells in desk sheet to paste to
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
      :=False, Transpose:=True
         Else
    Msg = MsgBox("No Orange Data")
End If
```

I haven't tried much yet since I wanted to see if I was headed in the right direction. The above code works, it's just slow and take up a ton of pages in the module.

Comment: Is the macro in `Log Sheet.xlsm` ?

Comment: Yes, all the VBA is in that sheet.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA selecting cells is rarely necessary, better to reference them directly. You could use 2 arrays for the words and respective ranges but a dictionary can hold both in a single entry.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TransposeRows()
     Dim wb As Workbook, wsSrc As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet
     Dim fnd As Range, rngSearch As Range, ar As Variant
     Dim lastrow As Long, n As Long, t0 As Single
     t0 = Timer
     
     Set wb = ThisWorkbook
     Set wsSrc = Workbooks("Produce.xls").Sheets(1)
     Set wsTarget = Workbooks("Log Sheet.xlsm").ActiveSheet
     
     Dim dict, k, word As String
     Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
     With dict
         .Add "Apple", wsTarget.Range("Z3:Z26")
         .Add "Orange", wsTarget.Range("E3:E26")
         .Add "Banana", wsTarget.Range("F3:F26")
     End With
     
     With wsSrc
         lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
         Set rngSearch = .Range("C1:C" & lastrow)
         For Each k In dict.keys
            word = CStr(k)
            Set fnd = rngSearch.Find(What:=word & "*", After:=.Range("C1"), LookIn:= _
                xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not fnd Is Nothing Then
                ar = fnd.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 24).Value
                ' target range in dict(key)
                dict(word).Value = Application.Transpose(ar)
                n = n + 1
            Else
                MsgBox "No " & word & " Data", vbExclamation
            End If
        Next
     End With
     MsgBox n & " rows found", vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
     
End Sub
```